# Where is "upgrade target for ipad" in Xcode4

Tags: xcode, ios, ios4, ipad, xcode4

I'm running Build 4A304a and for the life of me I can't find it in Xcode or any reference to it on the internets.

any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Right-click the target and click Duplicate. Choose to Duplicate and Transition to iPad.

Comment: As a result of this operation, two .app files are created under Products directory. Shouldn't there only be just one?

Comment: I think it depends on what you're trying to do. I admit I haven't looked into whether the new target is iPad-only or made universal. You may have to do some extra work but the duplication will take care of the resources at least.

Answer (score 27):

Select your project in the Project Navigator, click your target, and then click the Summary tab. You can switch your iOS Application Target there to Universal.

Here's a screenshot:

[image]

Comment: If you are following along with the PragProg iPad Programming book written for Xcode 3.x in mind this answer is the path you want to take, and choose to duplicate the main window when prompted.