# Phonegap - configuring debug and release builds in xcode

Tags: javascript, xcode, cordova

How can I pass different variables into my phonegap javascript depending on whether I have xcode configured for debug or release?  Most specifically right now I want to be able to switch whether the app connects to my local dev server or to the real cloud server.

One option would be if the javascript can just detect which build type is happening, then I can store both sets of urls in .js code and choose appropriately.

Somewhat better would be if there was some place to store the different urls in Xcode, like maybe in a `.plist` or something -- I'm not real good with XCode or Objective-C (thus phonegap) so I don't know if that's even a normal practice.

Ideally I can do this with just javascript and IDE configuration changes.  If I need to change anything in Objective-C, the answer must be extremely specific about what to do.

Comment: In C/C++ there are different macro's set for `DEBUG` and `RELEASE` mode. In Objective-C too there should be something similar I thnk. that you can check with `#ifdef`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IN XCode we have targets for every application. By default you get one target for each application.

Duplicate the target with the inbuilt option you have in xCode. So one for local testing and the other for live mode. You can have both the targets in release mode too here.

Every target in xCode has separate .plist file for defining some settings and yes having your code base in common. Now put your local server url in target_test's plist and real server url in target_live's plist.

Your code should read from the respective plist during run time.

[Have a look](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5355958/where-is-upgrade-target-for-ipad-in-xcode4)

Comment: You probably have to write a plugin to read the plist file in a bundle.

Comment: @leopd there is no plugin found for solving this purpose. i will write one and update you with the git url..

Comment: @Leopd the plugin in the most simplest way is ready for use. https://github.com/futur/NSBundleFileEngine. Let me know if you need more info.

Comment: @Leopd the plugin is updated and the bug is fixed. check the repo for more details in the usage_sample.html. Apologies for the wrong brach push, my bad ;)

Comment: Right click any existing target and click duplicate.